# How to install RPM on OSX using macports

Tags: macos, macports, osx-mavericks

I'm attempting to use macports to install rpm on OSX 10.9.  I initially hit this problem, and solved it with the provided patch file: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/40128

Now I am getting the following error:

```
:info:build libtool: link: cannot find the library `/opt/local/lib/libpopt.la' or unhandled argument `/opt/local/lib/libpopt.la'
```

I did a port install popt and I got a libpopt.a and a couple others, but no libpopt.la.

How do I get libpopt.la so I can install the rpm package?